# react call method within render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call my method `onModelSelect` automatically if there is only 1 item in the this.props.models array

`{this.props.modelCheck && <div>{this.props.modelCheck.map(item => {()=>this.onModelSelect(item.id)} )}</div>}`

If I attach the method to an onClick event handler it works, but on it's own I'm unsure of the syntax to use as it does nothing when the component renders

```
 export default class App extends Component {
        onModelSelect = (modelId) => {
          this.props.selectModel(modelId);
          this.props.setModelSelected(true);
          console.log('test')
          console.log('modelId',modelId)
        }
        render() {

          return(
            <div>
                {this.props.modelCheck && <div>{this.props.modelCheck.map(item => {()=>this.onModelSelect(item.id)} )}</div>}
              {this.props.models.map(model =>
                <div onClick={()=> this.onModelSelect(model.id)}>Select Model</div>
              )}
            </div>
          )
        }
      }

      const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        const modelCheck = getFilteredSelectableModels(state).length === 1 && getFilteredSelectableModels(state)

        return {
          modelCheck,
        };
      };

      const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return bindActionCreators({
          ...settingDropActions,
        }, dispatch);
      };

      export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SettingDropModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding this line into your render method:

```
{this.props.models.length === 1 && this.props.models.map(model => ()=>this.onModelSelect(model.id))}
```

First of all `.map` in react JSX should be used to generate array of elements, which is not happening here. So this implementation is not correct.

To call `onModelSelect` method if there is only one model, you should call it in `componentDidMount` react lifecycle method.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.models.length === 1){
        this.onModelSelect(this.props.models[0].id);
    }
}
```

Comment: that line was there in error , I will try moving it to componentDidMount

Comment: It will surely work when you move to `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work when placed in `componentDidMount()` but it did work when placed into `componentWillReceiveProps()`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.models.length === 1){
      this.onModelSelect(this.props.models[0].id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, That means that on first render of component `this.props.models` is not available. Hence you have to write it into `componentWillReceiveProps`. But there is one fix: you should use `nextProps` instead of `this.props` in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Ideally you should write it in both of the function.